Can I get the device-side pointer to a CUDA kernel using its mangled symbol name?
Note: In case the post seems long, one can directly jump to the section starting with "I was wondering.." at the end, in case one wants to skip the buildup/context.

Buildup/Context:
For the code mentioned in the post, it is the __nv_cudaEntityRegisterCallback function injected by the nvcc compiler, which registers the host side kernel's name/symbol ((void (*)(double*, double*, double*, int))vecAdd) with the symbol_Z6vecAddPdS_S_i on the device for resolution by GPU by some lookup table during cudaLaunchKernel API call (to get hold of the device pointer), as mentioned here.
Similarly, for a __device__ function pointer definition to get hold of the device pointer of the kernel vecAdd as:
typedef void (*fp)(double *, double *, double *, int);
__device__ fp kernelPtrvecAdd = vecAdd;

is even handled by the __nv_cudaEntityRegisterCallback function.
static void __nv_cudaEntityRegisterCallback(void **__T23) { 
    // Save the fat binary handle for managed runtime
    __nv_save_fatbinhandle_for_managed_rt(__T23);
    ...
    ...
    // Register the vecAdd function
    __cudaRegisterFunction(
        __T23, 
        (const char*)((void (*)(double*, double*, double*, int))vecAdd), 
        "_Z6vecAddPdS_S_i", 
        "_Z6vecAddPdS_S_i", 
        -1, (uint3*)0, (uint3*)0, (dim3*)0, (dim3*)0, (int*)0
    );
 
     // Register the kernelPtrvecAdd variable
    __cudaRegisterVar(
        __T23, 
        (char*)&::kernelPtrvecAdd, 
        "kernelPtrvecAdd", 
        "kernelPtrvecAdd", 
        0, 8UL, 0, 0
    );
    ...
    ...
}

The above code snippet can be obtained by compiling the post.cu file here as:
$ nvcc -cuda post.cu -o post.cu.cpp.ii


But consider the situation in the example given below:
Where I have the following setup:
vecAdd.cu
// vecAdd.cu
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// CUDA kernel that adds two vectors, each thread handles one element of c
__global__ void vecAdd(double *a, double *b, double *c, int n) {
    int id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (id < n) {
        c[id] = a[id] + b[id];
    }
}

Compiled as
$ nvcc -cubin -arch=sm_75 vecAdd.cu -o vecAdd.cubin

main.cu
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda.h>

#define CUDA_SAFECALL(call)                                                 \
    {                                                                       \
        call;                                                               \
        cudaError err = cudaGetLastError();                                 \
        if (cudaSuccess != err) {                                           \
            fprintf(                                                        \
                stderr,                                                     \
                "Cuda error in function '%s' file '%s' in line %i : %s.\n", \
                #call, __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString(err));        \
            fflush(stderr);                                                 \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                             \
        }                                                                   \
    }

#define SAFECALL_DRV(call)                                                  \
    {                                                                       \
        CUresult err = call;                                                \
        if (err != CUDA_SUCCESS) {                                          \
            const char *errStr;                                             \
            cuGetErrorString(err, &errStr);                                 \
            fprintf(                                                        \
                stderr,                                                     \
                "CUDA Driver API error in function '%s' file '%s' in line %i : %s.\n", \
                #call, __FILE__, __LINE__, errStr);                         \
            fflush(stderr);                                                 \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                             \
        }                                                                   \
    }
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n = 100000000;  // Size of the vectors
    if (argc > 1) n = atoi(argv[1]);

    // Initialize CUDA Driver API
    cuInit(0);

    // Get a CUDA device and create a context
    CUdevice device;
    CUcontext context;
    cuDeviceGet(&device, 0);
    cuCtxCreate(&context, 0, device);
    cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain(&context, device);
    // Load the module from vecAdd.o
    CUmodule module;
    SAFECALL_DRV(cuModuleLoad(&module, "vecAdd.cubin"));

    // Create a CUDA stream for asynchronous execution
    cudaStream_t stream;
    cudaStreamCreate(&stream);

    // Host and device vectors
    double *h_a, *h_b, *h_c;
    double *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;
    size_t bytes = n * sizeof(double);

    // Allocate host memory
    h_a = (double *)malloc(bytes);
    h_b = (double *)malloc(bytes);
    h_c = (double *)malloc(bytes);

    // Initialize host vectors
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        h_a[i] = sin(i) * sin(i);
        h_b[i] = cos(i) * cos(i);
        h_c[i] = 0;
    }

    CUfunction vecAddFunc;
    SAFECALL_DRV(cuModuleGetFunction(&vecAddFunc, module, "_Z6vecAddPdS_S_i"));
    printf("vecAdd: %p\n", vecAddFunc);

    // Allocate device memory
    cudaMallocAsync(&d_a, bytes, stream);
    cudaMallocAsync(&d_b, bytes, stream);
    cudaMallocAsync(&d_c, bytes, stream);

    // Copy data from host to device
    cudaMemcpyAsync(d_a, h_a, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream);
    cudaMemcpyAsync(d_b, h_b, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream);

    // Time the kernel execution
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cudaEventRecord(start, stream);
        int gridSize = (int)ceil((float)n / 1024);
        void *args[] = { &d_a, &d_b, &d_c, &n };

        SAFECALL_DRV(cuLaunchKernel(
                        vecAddFunc,      // Kernel function
                        gridSize, 1, 1,  // Grid dimensions
                        1024, 1, 1,      // Block dimensions
                        0,               // Shared memory
                        stream,          // Stream
                        args,            // Kernel arguments
                        NULL             // Extra (not used)
                    ));

        cudaStreamSynchronize(stream);
        cudaEventRecord(stop, stream);
        cudaEventSynchronize(stop);

        float time = 0;
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
        printf("Iteration %d: Time vecAdd: %f ms\n", i, time);
    }

    // Copy array back to host using async memory copy
    cudaMemcpyAsync(h_c, d_c, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream);
    
    // Release device memory using async memory deallocation
    cudaFreeAsync(d_a, stream);
    cudaFreeAsync(d_b, stream);
    cudaFreeAsync(d_c, stream);

    // Synchronize the stream to ensure everything is done
    cudaStreamSynchronize(stream);

    // Sum up vector c and print result divided by n, this should equal 1 within error
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) sum += h_c[i];
    printf("Final sum = %f; sum/n = %f (should be ~1)\n", sum, sum / n);

    // Clean up resources
    cudaStreamDestroy(stream);
    cudaEventDestroy(start);
    cudaEventDestroy(stop);
    free(h_a);
    free(h_b);
    free(h_c);
    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_b);
    cudaFree(d_c);

    // Destroy the CUDA context
    cuCtxDestroy(context);

    return 0;
}

$ nvcc  main.cu -lcuda

./a.out vecAdd: 0x56400fc49640
Iteration 0: Time vecAdd: 6.092896 ms
...
Iteration 9: Time vecAdd: 6.029056 ms
Final sum = 100000000.000000; sum/n = 1.000000 (should be ~1)

In the above code, I load the cubin of the vecAdd kernel code in the main.cu file and then get hold of the host side stub (as is evident from the address 0x56400fc49640) of the vecAdd kernel using cuModuleGetFunction passing just the symbol name of the kernel function as a string (as in _Z6vecAddPdS_S_i) (though the manged cpp-style name has the function signature info in it, in this particular situation, but it might not always be the case) using which I can launch the kernel using cuLaunchKernel.
nvcc -cuda main.cu main.cu.cpp.ii output file (main.cu.cpp.ii) does not contain any register function line in the __nv_cudaEntityRegisterCallback, but
nvcc -cuda vecAdd.cu vecAdd.cu.cpp.ii contains a register function entry for _Z6vecAddPdS_S_i. So, I guess cuModuleLoad and cuModuleGetFunction is installing that in the main executable.

I was wondering,

Is there any way by which using just the string _Z6vecAddPdS_S_i I could get hold of the device side pointer of the kernel vecAdd. Just as using cuModuleGetFunction we get hold of the host pointer of vecAdd kernel.
Or, if vecAdd.cu was compiled as vecAdd.o using nvcc -c vecAdd.cu -o vecAdd.o -rdc=true and main be compiled as nvcc main.cu vecAdd.o, to define__device__ function pointer requires us to know the signature of vecAdd (for the external linkage) in main.cu:

typedef void (*fp)(double *, double *, double *, int);
extern __global__ void vecAdd(double *a, double *b, double *c, int n);
__device__ fp kernelPtr = vecAdd;

Is there a way out, where I can get the device function pointer of vecAdd without the knowledge of its signature (along the line of cuda dynamic parallelism; here, there is a discussion, but unfortunately both the parent and child kernel are in the module itself.)?

Your question is super long and complicated (or at least seems complicated). Can we ignore everything until "I was wondering"?

@einpoklum may be you can, provided you are able to get the context.

Also, for this kind of work, consider using my CUDA Modern C++ API wrappers, which specifically make working with modules much nicer, and preclude the need for all those SAFECALL macros. Example

As far as I can tell, you never get device-side function pointers of kernels.
What you may get, e.g. using cuModuleGetFunction, is a CUfunction, which is defined as:
typedef CUfunc_st * CUfunction;

so, the pointer isn't to the function, nor to a function stub, but to an opaque structure used by the CUDA driver.
For functions you compile "statically" along with your executable, and load together with it, there is indeed a host-side stub which you use or call. AFAICT, there is no straightforward mechanism for getting CUfunction's by (mangled) name, but TBH I've not tried to hard to achieve this feat.
However, you can go from the stub to the CUfunction, with CUDA version 11.0 or higher:
extern __host__ cudaError_t cudaGetFuncBySymbol(
    cudaFunction_t* functionPtr, 
    const void*     symbolPtr);

and cudaFunction_t is really just a CUfunc_st * like CUfunction.

And a general comment:
Personally, I advise against using the CUDA runtime API and the direct placements of kernels along with host-side C++ code. These "kiddie wheels" might seem convenient initially, but once you start doing more serious work, the detriments far outweight the limited convenience benefits. In fact, it becomes even less convenient.
Even if you want to compile and device-link your kernels apriori - do that, keep fatbin files, and load them. Doing so is pretty easy and straightforward; with my wrappers, the use of such kernels is nothing more than:
auto fatbin = somehow_get_a_fatbin_file_into_some_string(fatbin_filename);
auto module = cuda::module::create(device, fatbin);
auto kernel = module.get_kernel(mangled_kernel_name);
cuda::launch(kernel, launch_config, first_arg, another_arg, yet_another);

(and that's when you use the primary context, which I also don't advise, but let's not get into that.)

I was thinking along the line of cuda dynamic parallelism, where the child kernel is loaded through module in the main code and there you have a parent kernel through which you launch that loaded kernel as a child. Loading through cudaGetFunction gives us the CUfunction as you said. But that can't be used inside a kernel to launch a child kernel. I hope I am able to explain my rationale. Any trick to get hold of device-side handle of the kernel? Or at the point there is no way out?
